# AJAX via jQuery updates the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script, which connects to the DB, does a simple select and returns a single number back. The script works fine, I can test it by adding

```
action="search_ODtime.php" method="POST"
```

to my form. But the whole thing does not work. The whole page is getting refreshed and I am getting nothing back. I killed the whole day trying to figure out what is wrong here. Does anyone have any idea?

My html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#time_search').bind('submit', function() {
            var origin = $('#origin').val();
            var destination = $('#destination').val();
            alert(origin);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_ODtime.php",
                data: 'origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#search_results').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
      });
      </script>
      </head>
      <fieldset style="font-size:11pt;  opacity: 1; color: white;">
        <form id="time_search">
          Orinig: 
          <input name="origin" id="origin" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="97">
          <br>
          Destination: 
          <input name="destination" id="destination" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="97">
          <br>

          <input type="submit" value="Get travel time" name="submit" id="submit" style="border-radius: 5px; display: block; margin: 10px auto 10px 0;">

        </form>
        Travel time:
        <div id="search_results">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is your form is getting submitted. You can either: a) remove the form entirely and change the submit button to a regular button, then bind your event to the button instead of the form, or b) prevent the form from submitting.

jQuery passes the event object to every event handler. The event object has a method called `preventDefault()` which prevents, well, the default action, whether it's submitting a form or linking to a page or whatever.

You need to pass the event into the function by adding a variable for it, and then call it's `preventDefault()` method to prevent the form from submitting and your page being refreshed.

```
$('#time_search').bind('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var origin = $('#origin').val();
    var destination = $('#destination').val();
    alert (origin);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"search_ODtime.php",
        data: 'origin='+origin+'&destination='+destination,
        success: function(data){ $('#search_results').html(data); }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It works perfectly now. I just started with AJAX today and the tutorials I followed did not mention anything about the preventDefault() method.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to mention:

**First:**

When submitting a form via AJAX you need to prevent the browser from its default submitting behaviour and thus from refreshing the page.

```
('#time_search').bind('submit',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
```

**Second:**

Try sending your data in the **JSON format** eg. {"origin": origin, "destination": destination}

Comment: Please *don't* keep your answer short.

Comment: I see no need to make a simple answer complicated.

Comment: "If you can't explain it simply then you don't understand it well enough." ..you should actually *explain* it though.

Comment: @RicoOcepek Thank you for pointing out all this. The first point actually did solve the problem. I will read about the difference between $_POST and $_REQUEST, but what is the advantage of sending the data in JSON format? Just the matter of convenience?

Comment: Are you claiming that `$_POST` is deprecated in php? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: If that is what you are claiming, I would be interested in seeing where you are citing that from.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks for correcting me, i was mixing up some things..